# I can't set border for an HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm learning HTML and a little CSS. I've got a problem during setting table border for an HTML border.
I type the CSS codes, also the width and height codes and text-alignment codes work fine but the border code doesn't work.
Here is my codes:

```html
<table>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      text-align: left;
      border: 10px red;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 800px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
  <tr>
    <th>Player LastName</th>
    <th>Player Jersey Number</th>
    <th>nationallity</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Reus</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Haaland</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>norway</td>
        <tr>
          <td>Kobel</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Switzerland</td>
</table>
```

and here is the result in my web:[result in my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS5OL.jpg)

Comment: The HTML is invalid; The only valid children of `table` are `caption`, `tr`, `colgroup`, `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the border *style*  to your border definition (solid, dotted or other): `border: 10px solid red;`

(AND you should close your `<tr>` tags!)

```css
table,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Player LastName</th>
    <th>Player Jersey Number</th>
    <th>nationallity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Reus</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Germany</td </tr>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Haaland</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>norway</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Kobel</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Switzerland</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best of luck on your learning path of HTML & CSS.

When you are using '**Border Shorthand**' always follow the syntax, your code is missing the border type. Reference here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border_shorthand.asp

Use this CSS code:

```
table,
th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 10px solid red;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type of border. For example `solid` or `dotted`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) for more info on the border property

```html
<table>
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      text-align: left;
      border: 10px solid red;
      width: 800px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
  <tr>
    <th>Player LastName</th>
    <th>Player Jersey Number</th>
    <th>nationallity</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Reus</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
      <tr>
        <td>Haaland</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>norway</td>
        <tr>
          <td>Kobel</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Switzerland</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned border type:

Here is the updated css code, please use following css code

```
  table,th,td {
            text-align: left;
            border: 10px red solid;
            width: 800px;
            height: 100px;
        }
```